# How to get user's facebook pages from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a website with Facebook Connect (using Facebooker2) and I would like to get the user's facebook pages.

Is there any plugin/gem for Ruby On Rails 3 to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254197/after-oauth-with-facebook-how-do-i-get-the-graph-of-the-pages-created-by-user) I figured out that Facebook calls **accounts** to the user's **pages**.

So, once you get the user using FBGprah, for example, you just write **@user.accounts** in order to make it work.